# How can I let Elasticsearch accept multiple json in one request?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch7 and create a pipeline based on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html.

The pipeline is to decode base64 like below:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": "ctx.decoded = ctx.data.decodeBase64();"
      }
    },
    {
      "json": {
        "field": "decoded",
        "add_to_root": true
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "decoded"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I receive error when I push data to the index:

`Response for request ff6dd42a-5694-4c17-b103-c37bae72af58 is not recognized as valid JSON or has unexpected fields. Raw response received: 400 {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"script_exception\",\"reason\":\"runtime error\",\"script_stack\":[\"ctx.decoded = ctx.data.decodeBase64();\",\"                      ^---- HERE\"],\"script\":\"ctx.decoded = ctx.data.decodeBase64();\",\"lang\":\"painless\",\"position\":{\"offset\":22,\"start\":0,\"end\":38}}],\"type\":\"script_exception\",\"reason\":\"runtime error\",\"script_stack\":[\"ctx.decoded = ctx.data.decodeBase64();\",\"                      ^---- HERE\"],\"script\":\"ctx.decoded = ctx.data.decodeBase64();\",\"lang\":\"painless\",\"position\":{\"offset\":22,\"start\":0,\"end\":38},\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"null_pointer_exception\",\"reason\":\"Cannot invoke \\\"Object.getClass()\\\" because \\\"callArgs[0]\\\" is null\"}},\"status\":400}`

The reason is that the json is not a single one. It is a multiple json data:

```
{
 "data": "..."
}
{
 "data": "..."
}
```

They are not valid json array so how can I let Elasticsearch piepline accepts this format?

Comment: You mean that your Base64 encoded JSON is 10MB big??? According to the error it simply looks like the data field is null. Possible?

Comment: I realise that it is not a size issue. It is a format issue. I have updated the question

Comment: I don't think it's the problem. Can you share a single base64 encoded document in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: Also the ingest pipeline is only there to process one document at a time

Comment: Is there a processor I can use to convert above data to a json array?

Comment: No and it wouldn't help you because you'd have no way to create separate documents from that array. You probably need to introduce Logstash to slice and dice that data before sending it to ES

Comment: I'm curious about the use case behind this? 1) Why are the documents b64 encoded in the first place (i.e. it takes more space and thus longer to transmit) and 2) why are multiple documents encoded together (not even in an array)?